# How to check the existence of a folder outside the wordpress path in php?

Tags: php, wordpress

The default path of the WordPress theme is the following address:

```
public_html/wp-content/themes/theme-child/function.php
```

In this `function.php` file, I want to check the existence of a directory at the following address or path:

```
public_html/myfiles/music/rock
```

If the `rock` folder is found, display a message (the name of `rock` is a variable)

I did this through the following codes, but it doesn't recognize the existing folder and displays the folder not found message!

```
$wurl = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/';
$dir = 'myfiles/music/';
$type = 'rock';
$link = $wurl . $dir . $type;   

if (file_exists($link)) {
  echo "The directory exists.";
} else {
  echo "error";
}
```

or

```
if (file_exists($dir . $type)) {
  echo "The directory exists.";
} else {
  echo "error";
}
```

or

```
if(file_exists($link) && is_dir($link)) {
  echo "The directory exists.";
} else {
  echo "error";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ABSPATH` instead of your web URL. It's more reliable than using URL.

```php
$dir = 'myfiles/music/';
$type = 'rock';
$pathToCheck = ABSPATH . $dir . $type;
```

You can check directory existence using the `is_dir` or `file_exists` methods, as you mentioned in your question.

Also, make sure that the directory has the correct privileges; at least the user of your web server can access those files and directories.